# How do I run this code in R every five minutes?

Tags: python, r

Here is my code

```
file_names <- dir()
tbl <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
```

I want this to run every five minutes. I'm running a big reoccurring script in Python that is drawing live data and saving it out into a new excel sheet into this directory every minute. Because I am using the sleep function (and do not know another way, very new to coding), this blocks me from running other python scripts to make analysis on this data that I'm pulling live - which is what is necessary for me. I would like this code in R to run every five minutes so I am sure I am capturing all new information being added to the directory from my Python script.

(Bonus points if you can help me re-write my python script so its no longer blocking me from running other scripts in python while this script is still ran every minute)

Comment: if you want it to be entirely in R you can use sys.sleep. still I'd use the system cron to run such a job.

Comment: little confused - most of the json and coding is in python currently. but thats where I have my first reoccuring script that pulls data once every minute. Do you mean I can use sys.sleep in python to keep everything in python? Or I can use sys.sleep in R to do this?

Comment: You know it's entirely possible to run more than one script at a time right? I love R but there really isn't a reason you couldn't use Python for this too.

Comment: Instead of using sys.sleep in python, you can configure cron to run the python script once every 5 minutes. If the last line of your python script is code to build a data frame in python with the csv file just created,  there is no need to use R for this.

Comment: What operating system are you running? I suspect you can run more than one Python script at a time.

Comment: I'm confused. You show R code that you want run every 5 minutes, but say that it is blocking your python script. You can have this run periodically using either the [`later`](https://github.com/r-lib/later) (quasi-threaded) or [`callr`](https://github.com/r-lib/callr) (multi-proc) fairly easily. But that's in R.

Comment: No. In Python - I'm retrieving LIVE DATA from a website every minute. This is every sixty seconds. I'm currently using time.sleep(60) to tell my code to go back into the JSON to retrieve the new information every sixty seconds. This is BLOCKING - so to run analysis on the live data I am pulling I decided to use R. But I combining all the excel csv's (the live data that is pulled every minute) into one dataframe. I want this to occur every five minutes in R because I currently am BLOCKED from running script in Python

Comment: No you're blocked from running in the same script with how you've coded it. I highly suspect you could recode to do what you want in the same script or even better just do what you want in a different python script and have both running.

Comment: I get what you're saying but I don't know how to do that - I'm new to coding in Python. Little more experienced with R. Which is why I shifted to do analysis in R but if there is a way to make my code better in Python so my script isn't BLOCKING me anymore then I'm all ears. Should I edit post with my python code that is currently reoccuring every sixty seconds?

Comment: Yes, it would be a good idea to ask a more specific question about how to solve the underlying problem completely in python (e.g. how do I extract data from a website every 60 seconds and aggregate the contents into a data frame once per 5 minutes without blocking?), and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Your current question about R is addressing a symptom (python program blocks) not the root problem.

Answer (score 2):

This will run as long as the R session is open. Just change `3` to `300` to have a 5 minute delay and put in your own function. Per the comments on your initial post, this probably isn't a very good way to accomplish your actual goal.

```
i = 0
while(TRUE) {
  print(paste("its been", i, "seconds since this started, give or take a bit"))
  i = i + 3
  Sys.sleep(3)
}
```